# Can we restrict the web page of GitBlit to be accessed from the localhost interface only

Tags: git, localhost, loopback, gitblit

We are using the GitBlit GO. We bind the https protocol to all interfaces for git and, for the authentication, we have set the client certificate is required. But, we would also like the web page to be accessed only from the loopback interface(localhost). Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the answer. Will it be possible if we have using the GitBlit war and add the filter to our servlet container to restrict the access to the web page?

Comment: You could easily implement a filter that passes requests through for `/r/` and `/git/` but rejects requests for everything else based on request ip address.  Alternatively, you could put up an Nginx frontend which perhaps does the same thing.  Or you could bind the http interface to localhost and only use SSH for git ops.